# Missing aesthetics geometry

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I am looking to create a map using the following dataset:
[image: dataset]

with the shapefile of:
[image]

Here is my R code:

```r
library("tidyverse")
library("dplyr")
library("sf")
library("ggplot2")
library("tmap")
library("tmaptools")
library("RColorBrewer")


data = readr::read_csv("C:/Users/amanm/Desktop/annualincomedata2.csv")


localauthorities2 <- read_sf("C:/Users/amanm/Desktop/localauthorities2.dbf")

mymap <- merge(data,localauthorities2)

ggplot(mymap) + geom_sf(aes(fill = Total)) + scale_fill_viridis_c()
```

Upon running the code I am given an error code:

```
> ggplot(mymap) + geom_sf(aes(fill = Total)) + scale_fill_viridis_c()
Error in `check_required_aesthetics()`:
! stat_sf requires the following missing aesthetics: geometry
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Any advice would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding label to geom\_sf returns error for stat\_sf\_coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59084529/adding-label-to-geom-sf-returns-error-for-stat-sf-coordinates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should merge the `data` to the `localauthorities2`, not the other way around. This way, you add the `data.frame` object (`data`) to an `sf` object (`localauthorities2`) as attributes, thus, the `mymap` object is still an `sf` object with geometry.

```
mymap <- merge(localauthorities2, data)
```

Comment: The code works now but im now im encountered with ```Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2mb``` I have 32gbs of ram if this helps

Answer (score -1):

You need to bring your spatial data in with

```
localauthorities2 <- st_read("C:/Users/amanm/Desktop/localauthorities2.shp")
```

Comment: From doing this im still getting the same error.

Comment: Try adding inherit.aes=FALSE into your geom_sf call.  Is hard to say what the issue is without a reproducible data to work off.

Comment: And I was off base, read_sf works jsut as well as st_read.